# By Using Camera 2 api while using External USB Camera the Captured image are just black Images and Thumpnails

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.camera4;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    private Button takePictureButton,nextactivity;
    private TextureView textureView;
    private ImageView imageView;


    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    private String cameraId;
    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;

    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private File file;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private String folderName="Myphotodir";
    private File folder;
    byte[] bytes1 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        takePictureButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_takepicture);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        assert takePictureButton != null;
        nextactivity = findViewById(R.id.nextactivity);
        nextactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,AndroidCameraApi.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            //open your camera here
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            closeCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            closeCamera();
        }
    };
    final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            createCameraPreview();

        }
    };

    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    protected void takePicture() {
        if (null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        Log.d("takePicture()","started");
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(1);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            folder = new File(folderName);
            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFilename = "image"+".jpg";
            file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(folderName),"/"+imageFilename);
            if (!folder.exists())
            {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }

            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader1) {
                    Log.d("image available","true");
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader1.acquireNextImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                        image.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    Log.d("save()","called");
                    OutputStream output = null;
                    try {
                        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        output.write(bytes);
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved:" + file.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                    Log.d("image location=",String.valueOf(file));
                    Log.d("image result=",String.valueOf(result));
                }

                public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int bufferSize = 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    int len = 0;
                    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
                        bytes1 =byteBuffer.toByteArray();
                    }
                    return bytes1;
                    }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }

    protected void updatePreview() {
        if (null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        //closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        closeCamera();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @MainThread
    private void closeCamera() {
        if (null != cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader) {
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }
}
```

## Code Explanation

- While the app started the camera has been opened by calling openCamera(); function In that function I have been getting the manifest permission and then opening the camera [0]
  While Clicking "takePicture(); function" I have been getting the captured image by using "
- ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);"
- I have been getting only one image and then by using
- ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener inside the listener I have been using
  image = reader1.acquireNextImage(); to acqure the captured image
- then I have been converting the image to byte and then pass it to the "save() function" in that function I have been saving my captured image and then save them in my local storage
- In reader.setOnImageAvailableListener I have been calling onCaptureCompleted to show the image location and then calling the "createCameraPreview() Function"

### Description

- I have been using the above code to capture an image and save it in local storage
- While capturing the image by using a mobile phone with the mobile internal camera it is working properly
- While I tried to take pictures from the POS Billing machine using the External USB camera the camera shows the live feed in ` While I click the "Take Picture Button" The image saved just a black image
- While clicking the "Take Picture Button" it successfully passes through "ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener" which is used to get the acquirenextimage() and call the "save() function" Which is used to save images in my local storage

**What Do I need**

- The above code is working properly when I capture images from my phone and when I have been trying from my POS device the using EXternal USB camera it just saves a black image
- Please provide me an explanation of what I am doing wrong or why the problem acquires the POS device only.

**My LogCat**

```
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (10183) for package com.example.camera4 ----------------------------
2022-12-23 10:48:56.977   561-7931  ActivityManager         system_process                       E  getPackageFerformanceMode--ComponentInfo{com.example.camera4/com.example.camera4.MainActivity}----com.example.camera4
2022-12-23 10:48:56.980   561-5053  ActivityManager         system_process                       E  getPackageFerformanceMode--ComponentInfo{com.example.camera4/com.example.camera4.MainActivity}----com.example.camera4
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (11010) for package com.example.camera4 ----------------------------
2022-12-23 10:48:57.700 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/os/Trace;->TRACE_TAG_APP:J (light greylist, reflection)
2022-12-23 10:48:57.700 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2022-12-23 10:48:57.841 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
2022-12-23 10:48:57.841 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
2022-12-23 10:48:57.841 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
2022-12-23 10:48:57.841 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
2022-12-23 10:48:57.890 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection)
2022-12-23 10:48:57.958 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2022-12-23 10:48:57.959 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2022-12-23 10:48:58.130 11010-11010 Main                    com.example.camera4                  E  onResume
2022-12-23 10:48:58.142 11010-11010 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.camera4                  D  Skia GL Pipeline
2022-12-23 10:48:58.212 11010-11036 mali_so                 com.example.camera4                  I  [File] : hardware/arm/mali_so/driver/product/base/src/mali_base_kbase.c; [Line] : 876; [Func] : base_context_deal_with_version_affairs_rk_ext;
                                                                                                    arm_release_ver of this mali_so is 'r18p0-01rel0', rk_so_ver is '15@0'.
2022-12-23 10:48:58.213 11010-11036 mali_so                 com.example.camera4                  D  [File] : hardware/arm/mali_so/driver/product/base/src/mali_base_kbase.c; [Line] : 881; [Func] : base_context_deal_with_version_affairs_rk_ext;
                                                                                                    current process is NOT sf, to bail out.
2022-12-23 10:48:58.236 11010-11036 ConfigStore             com.example.camera4                  I  android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2022-12-23 10:48:58.236 11010-11036 ConfigStore             com.example.camera4                  I  android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2022-12-23 10:48:58.236 11010-11036 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.camera4                  I  Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2022-12-23 10:48:58.236 11010-11036 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.camera4                  D  Swap behavior 2
2022-12-23 10:48:58.247 11010-11036 mali_winsys             com.example.camera4                  D  EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2022-12-23 10:48:58.280 11010-11010 Main                    com.example.camera4                  E  is camera open
2022-12-23 10:48:58.281 11010-11010 CameraManagerGlobal     com.example.camera4                  I  Connecting to camera service
2022-12-23 10:48:58.294 11010-11010 camera level            com.example.camera4                  D  4
2022-12-23 10:48:59.024 11010-11010 Main                    com.example.camera4                  E  openCamera X
2022-12-23 10:48:59.086 11010-11036 GRALLOC-ROCKCHIP        com.example.camera4                  D  RK_GRAPHICS_VER=commit-id:dc44fa2
2022-12-23 10:48:59.110 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:48:59.146 11010-11036 chatty                  com.example.camera4                  I  uid=10072(com.example.camera4) RenderThread identical 10 lines
2022-12-23 10:48:59.150 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:48:59.153 11010-11036 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.camera4                  I  Davey! duration=973ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=17676652385667, Vsync=17676735718997, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=17676746187254, AnimationStart=17676746254045, PerformTraversalsStart=17676746778170, DrawStart=17676751392046, SyncQueued=17677553044460, SyncStart=17677553731626, IssueDrawCommandsStart=17677553857043, SwapBuffers=17677624795634, FrameCompleted=17677627029217, DequeueBufferDuration=510000, QueueBufferDuration=417000, 
2022-12-23 10:48:59.171 11010-11010 Choreographer           com.example.camera4                  I  Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2022-12-23 10:48:59.185 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
2022-12-23 10:48:59.185 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
2022-12-23 10:48:59.185 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceCounter(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (light greylist, reflection)
2022-12-23 10:48:59.202 11010-11010 Main                    com.example.camera4                  E  onOpened
2022-12-23 10:48:59.206 11010-11036 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.camera4                  I  Davey! duration=927ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=17676752273366, Vsync=17677635606664, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=17677645137927, AnimationStart=17677645220761, PerformTraversalsStart=17677646040052, DrawStart=17677646535011, SyncQueued=17677657101220, SyncStart=17677657157803, IssueDrawCommandsStart=17677657277970, SwapBuffers=17677676895764, FrameCompleted=17677679493347, DequeueBufferDuration=190000, QueueBufferDuration=661000, 
2022-12-23 10:48:59.476 11010-11024 [Gralloc]               com.example.camera4                  I  for nv12, w : 160, h : 120, pixel_stride : 160, byte_stride : 160, size : 38400; internalHeight : 120.
2022-12-23 10:48:59.483 11010-11024 [Gralloc]               com.example.camera4                  I  for nv12, w : 160, h : 120, pixel_stride : 160, byte_stride : 160, size : 38400; internalHeight : 120.
2022-12-23 10:48:59.503 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:48:59.507 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:48:59.518 11010-11024 [Gralloc]               com.example.camera4                  I  for nv12, w : 160, h : 120, pixel_stride : 160, byte_stride : 160, size : 38400; internalHeight : 120.
2022-12-23 10:48:59.524 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:49:19.945 11010-11024 [Gralloc]               com.example.camera4                  I  for nv12, w : 160, h : 120, pixel_stride : 160, byte_stride : 160, size : 38400; internalHeight : 120.
2022-12-23 10:49:19.986 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:49:19.990 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:49:19.999 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:49:20.055 11010-11010 takePicture()           com.example.camera4                  D  started
2022-12-23 10:49:20.476 11010-11035 image available         com.example.camera4                  D  true
2022-12-23 10:49:20.477 11010-11035 save()                  com.example.camera4                  D  called
2022-12-23 10:49:20.794 11010-11010 example.camera          com.example.camera4                  W  Long monitor contention with owner Camera Background (11035) at void android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(android.hardware.camera2.params.InputConfiguration, java.util.List, android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession$StateCallback, java.util.concurrent.Executor, int, android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest)(CameraDeviceImpl.java:636) waiters=0 in void android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$4.run() for 270ms
2022-12-23 10:49:20.793 11010-11035 image location=         com.example.camera4                  D  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.camera4/files/Myphotodir/image.jpg
2022-12-23 10:49:20.795 11010-11035 image result=           com.example.camera4                  D  android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult@37e6a4f
2022-12-23 10:49:20.805 11010-11010 data                    com.example.camera4                  D  onActivityResult: bytes size=2986
2022-12-23 10:49:20.807 11010-11010 data                    com.example.camera4                  D  
2022-12-23 10:49:20.833 11010-11023 [Gralloc]               com.example.camera4                  I  for nv12, w : 160, h : 120, pixel_stride : 160, byte_stride : 160, size : 38400; internalHeight : 120.
2022-12-23 10:49:20.837 11010-11023 [Gralloc]               com.example.camera4                  I  for nv12, w : 160, h : 120, pixel_stride : 160, byte_stride : 160, size : 38400; internalHeight : 120.
2022-12-23 10:49:20.853 11010-11059 [Gralloc]               com.example.camera4                  I  for nv12, w : 160, h : 120, pixel_stride : 160, byte_stride : 160, size : 38400; internalHeight : 120.
2022-12-23 10:49:20.869 11010-11036 mali_winsys             com.example.camera4                  D  EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2022-12-23 10:49:20.879 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:49:20.882 11010-11036 chatty                  com.example.camera4                  I  uid=10072(com.example.camera4) RenderThread identical 1 line
2022-12-23 10:49:20.885 11010-11036 <no-tag>                com.example.camera4                  D  set stream to NULL
2022-12-23 10:49:20.894 11010-11064 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.camera4                  D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-12-23 10:49:20.937 11010-11019 System                  com.example.camera4                  W  A resource failed to call release. 
2022-12-23 10:49:20.975 11010-11019 System                  com.example.camera4                  W  A resource failed to call release. 
2022-12-23 10:49:20.976 11010-11019 System                  com.example.camera4                  W  A resource failed to call close. 
2022-12-23 10:49:22.292 11010-11010 Volley response         com.example.camera4                  D  {"status":200,"body":"https:\/\/b2b-partnerapp-images.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\/itemweightdetails\/66955be7-47ec-4820-8cc9-0ac64fcebd8b.jpeg","isBase64Encoded":true}
2022-12-23 10:49:24.031 11010-11036 libEGL                  com.example.camera4                  W  EGLNativeWindowType 0x7995738010 disconnect failed
```

Comment: What is the value of `c.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)` as in this code here? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL

Comment: @MikeKim My Supported Hardware Level is 4

Comment: There is a one exception "Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." is that might be a problem?

Comment: what external camera and what android device are you using?